# Use of undeclared type "Decodable"/"Codable" in Swift 3

Tags: swift

So I'm following along with Apple's [Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) tutorial, via the storyboard, and I've run into an error trying the following:

```
struct GroceryStoreService: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let aisles: [Aisle]

    struct Aisle: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let shelves: [Shelf]

        struct Shelf: Decodable {
            let name: String
            let product: GroceryStore.Product
        }
    }
}
```

Only I'm getting the error:

`Use of undeclared type Decodable` - and the same with Codable.

I've checked other SO questions, trying cleaning and building, poking through the build phases and so far no luck on getting that sorted.

Comment: Don't you need Xcode 9/Swift 4 for Decodable/Codable?

Comment: Yeah, it's only available in Swift 4.

Comment: Oh damn it's new? Thanks, I'll upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need Xcode 9 and Swift 4 for using Codable.
Best writing I've been seen about it so far: https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375

If you have a sample JSON, you can use this JSON to Swift Codeable converter: http://danieltmbr.github.io/JsonCodeGenerator/